# Fixing keyboard stand

Tags: keyboard, stand

We've got Yamaha PSR-E453 keyboard. It allows mounting to a stand with screws. However, there are very few keyboard stands available that support this. Most keyboard stands are universal and you simply lay the keyboard on it, probably without mounting.

As our keyboard is placed in the children room, I'd prefer to fix it to the stand. Is this unusual? How am I supposed to fix a universal stand to the keyboard in order to prevent it from falling? If I drill holes to a stand, I would loose the possibility to adjust the keyboard height...

Answer (score 1):

Get a stand with four legs, in two pairs, one left, one right. They're far more stable - I will use only them for gigs, as the X stands aren't that stable. Put the keyboard against the wall, and there's little chance of it being pulled over or off the stand.

Comment: e,g, Ikea sell trestle legs strong enough to support a worktop. These would make a rock-solid keyboard stand.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS - Gear4music sells the stands I use, spring-loaded legs, height adjustable, solid. Could even screw the k'bd. from underneath, but not necessary.